# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 : Gateway not enforcing Throttling Limits

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have deployed API-M 2.1 in a distributed way (each component, GW, TM, KM are running in their own Docker image) on top on DC/OS 1.9 ( Mesos ).

We have issues to get the gateway to enforce throttling policies (should it be subscription tiers or app-level policies). Here is what we have managed to define so far:

1. The Traffic Manager itself does it job : it receives the event streams, analyzes them on the fly and pushes an event onto the JMS topic throttledata
2. The Gateway reads the message properly. 
   So basically we have discarded a communication issue.

However we found two potential issues:

1. In the event which is pushed to the TM component, the value of the appTenant is *null* (instead of carbon.super)- We have a single tenant defined.
2. When the gateway receives the throttling message, it decides to let the message go thinking the "stopOnQuotaReach" is set to false, when it is set to true (we checked the value in the database).

Digging into the source code, we related those two issues to a single source: the value for both values above are read from the authContext and apparently incorrectly set. We are stuck and running out of ideas of things to try and would need some pointers to what could be a potential source of the problem and things to check.

Can somebody help please ? 
Thanks- Isabelle.

Comment: Is the throttling limits not enforcing for subscription tiers only? Or it's not works for boh app tiers and subscription tiers?

Comment: Also even though appTenant is null, we don't take into the consideration when generating the subscccription throttle key or the application level throttle key. Hence it shouldn't be have aany effect for enforcing throttling limits.

Comment: One thing we need to check is whether throttle decision is comes to gateway through JMS

Answer (score 0):

Is there two TM with HA enabled available in the system?

If the TM is HA enabled, how gateways publish data to TM. Is it load balanced data publishing or failover data publishing to the TMs?

Did you follow below articles to configure the environment with respect to your deployment?

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/10/article-scalable-traffic-manager-deployment-patterns-for-wso2-api-manager-part-1/

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/10/article-scalable-traffic-manager-deployment-patterns-for-wso2-api-manager-part-2/

Is throttling completely not working in your environment?

Have you noticed any JMS connection related logs in gateways nodes?

Comment: Harsha, some additional comments: we are sure the JMS exchange works, because as I mentioned, the GW consumes BUT decides to let the request go because QuotaOnReach is not set, which is not true. The code shows this verification is done against the authContext. So one question is: when is the value of authContext set ? If you could point to the precise location in the code, we might be able to narrow where the issue comes from. Thanks.

Comment: is it a issue with QuotaOnReach not set properly? Since it's works locally it's bit stange. QuotaOnReach attribute is coming from the key manager. Do you have any custimization ti KM?

Comment: It  is properly set in the database. We have not done anything special at the KM level (except that it runs in its own container)  - Would the KM read it from the database and fill the authContext ? How/where is the context passed to the gateway then ? Thanks.

Comment: That value is coming from KM side. During the key manager call, we are taking that value and return to gateway side. Then it will set to the auth context. Can you try adding new tier and assign it to the database and try?

Answer (score 0):

In these tests, we have disabled HA to avoid possible complications. Neither subscription nor app throttling policies are working, both because parameters that should have values have not the adequate value (appTenant, stopOnQuotaReach).
Our scenario is far more basic. If we go with one instance of each component, it fails as Isabelle described. And the only thing we know is that both parameters come from the Authentication Context.

Thank you!